# Max & Min highchart line

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to graphic some values, I have this part, then I want to add some `max and min` line, I could do this creating another series and adding the min/max value that I want, the problem here is that my value series is an array of `n elements` so I want to know if I could create the min/max series for example just doing `data: [2]` and put the line in all the width of my chart. Something like this:

[image]

If there is no way to do this, just if is possible doing: `data[2, 2, 2,.... n]` is possible to show only the first and the last point and hide the rest of them?

[Here is my working code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENeoEG?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plotLines` for this.

Example:

```
yAxis: {
  softMax: max,
  min: 0,
  plotLines: [{
    value: min,
    width: 1,
    color: 'rgba(204,0,0,0.75)'
  },{
    value: max,
    width: 1,
    color: 'rgba(204,0,0,0.75)'
  }]
}
```

Updated pen:

- http://codepen.io/jlbriggs/pen/LbJQEV

Alternatively, if you really want it to be a series, you can grab the min and max x values, and provide your data as arrays of `[x,y]` pairs.  Something like:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Actual Series'
  ...
},{
  name: 'Max',
  data: [[xMin,yMax],[xMax,yMax]]
},{
  name: 'Min',
  data: [[xMin,yMin],[xMax,yMin]]
}]
```

Comment: Thank! I'll use plotLines